# Disable the "Save as button" from videos like youtube

Tags: javascript, html, security, html5-video

I just want to ask that how can we disable the "save as" option from the context menu while playing a  video, just like youtube does.

For a demo see the image below-

[image: Youtube player, with "save video as" option disabled]

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept 'right click' events and replace menus or disable the right click functionality on any web page element by using the contextmenu event in HTML5.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event

This includes the example shared below:

```js
noContext = document.getElementById('noContextMenu');

noContext.addEventListener('contextmenu', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<p id="noContextMenu">The context menu has been disabled on this paragraph.</p>
<p>But it has not been disabled on this one.</p>
```

However, it's worth mentioning that this is a very basic measure to stop someone downloading your video - anyone with basic knowledge will be able to bypass this and still download the video.

In fact, there is not really anything you can do to stop someone downloading a video if you want to make it viewable on the browser as the browser has to download it to play it and there are many ways of copying. If preventing copying is important to you the usual approach is to encrypt the content and use some form of secure method, e.g. your own simple secure key sharing or a commercial DRM, to share the encryption keys. Even with this someone can record the content with a camera pointed at the screen. If at that point you now want to be able to trace the source of the copied content then visible or invisible forensic watermarking approaches may be appropriate.

Ultimately, you have to decide what exactly you are trying to prevent and how much effort it is worth investing - i.e. how may security hurdles it is worth investing in to deter copying.

Comment: Hey, @Mick I have used this method of disabling the context menu, But this is not useful, If the user disables the javascript, that's why I was asking something like YouTube player do. As you can see in the above image, The context menu is still showing but, the "save as" option is disabled

Comment: @AnkitBrijwasi - The browser YouTube Player is usually (possibly always) a HTML5 video player now - i.e. also using Javascript. You can use a player like VideoJS and customise the context menu but ultimately you have to balance the effort against the ease with which people can work around it. There are many solutions for downloading YouTube videos available, for example, even with their resources. You can't stop people downloading but you can make it harder with the types of techniques you are looking at.